# CASE checks for NULL values inside IN clause

Tags: mysql

Can I use CASE inside IN statement? I am using mysql server and below is the query.

```
SELECT Id from Tenant 
where TenantId IN (
                    CASE WHEN 'someVariable' is NULL 
                    THEN  (select customer_id from Partners where partner_id = 'abc') 
                    ELSE ('xyz1','xyz2','xyz3') 
                    END
                  )
```

This throws error : 
    **`Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`**

I need to check for Null value in IN clause and then depend on the result need to either fire select on "Partners" table or just pass a list of predefined strings to IN clause. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create SQL Demo?? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT Id from Tenant 
WHERE TenantId IN (select customer_id from Partners where partner_id = 'abc')  
            AND somevariable IS NULL
      OR TenantId IN ('xyz1','xyz2','xyz3')  AND somevariable IS NOT NULL
```

or as alternative

```
SELECT Id from Tenant 
where TenantId IN (
                    CASE WHEN 'someVariable' is NULL 
                    THEN  (select customer_id from Partners where partner_id = 'abc') 
                    ELSE (select 'xyz1' AS id UNION ALL select 'xyz2' UNION ALL Select 'xyz3') 
                    END
                  )
```